# How to initiate fragment in fragmentActivity if it is added dynamically?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a `FragmentActivity` in which I am implementing navigation drawer, like if I select any item from drawer list then its fragment is opened in activity. Now my XML layout code to display fragments looks like this

```
<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        />
```

This means I have not any fragment tags in xml file but I open fragments dynamically from activity as below

```
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        if(session.isLoggedIn())
        {
            fragment = new SlidingFragment();
        }
        else
        {
            fragment = new LoginFragment();
        }
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new LoginFragment();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();}
```

Now I want to use putFragment to keep fragment state alive for one fragment when orientation changed.so, I coded below on my FragmentActivity's `onSaveInstanceState` method

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
   // Log.v(TAG, "In frag's on save instance state ");
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fr = new RandomFragment();
    manager.putFragment(outState, "randomFragment", fr);
}
```

here `fr` is an instance of fragment declared globally `Fragment fr` and `RandomFragment` is the fragment that I call in onPostExecute method of homeFragment AsyncTask class. I don't know initiation of RandomFragment is right or not that is `fr = new RandomFragment();`

Because I don't know how to find fragment by id or tag because there is no fragment tag in my activity layout file. I have just a fragment classes that extends Fragment and i call them like above. I am very confused here. I get the error

```
02-28 16:28:37.809: E/AndroidRuntime(4336): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment RandomFragment{4247d248} is not currently in the FragmentManager
```

When I try to change the orientation to landscape. I got this error in putFragment Line. And in onRestoreInstanceState method I write code for getFragment

```
@Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction t = manager.beginTransaction();
        if(savedInstanceState != null)
        {
            fr = (FragmentRandom)manager.getFragment(savedInstanceState, "randomFragment");
        }
        else
        {
            fr = new FragmentRandom();
        }
        t.add(fr, "randomFragment");
        t.commit();
    }
```

But when putFragment on `onSaveInstanceState` is execute that time I get error and my application stops forcefully so `onRestoreInstanceState` is not executing.

My actual problem is I don't know I initiate fragment in right way or not. And if it is right then why I get the error? Should I have to do anything with `onSaveInstanceState` method of fragment also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be trying to put a completely new instance of your fragment into the fragment manager. Not only will this cause the issue that you are seeing, if it had worked you wouldn't have been restoring the instance state of that fragment. Try finding the current fragment using the fragment manager.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fr = manager.findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container);
    manager.putFragment(outState, "randomFragment", fr);
}
```

Comment: i tried your code thank you fro reply but it gives fragment alredy added,unable to resume activity

Comment: I'd say that is because you are calling `t.add(fr, "randomFragment");` in onResumeInstanceState instead of `t.replace`